# (Google Analytics): Adding a custom dimension - Can't find the button

Tags: ios, button, google-analytics, customization, dimensions

I am aware that this is a quite silly question, however I can't seem to be able to add a new custom dimension as can be seen by the screenshot below (There should be a very visible button one would think!!) to my google analytics account, despite having 9 custom dimensions left. Currently, I am following this guide:

http://blog.bilue.com.au/accurate-apple-device-reporting-google-analytics/

To be able to track specific iOS devices from my app's userbase. Have they moved this option elsewhere? Or is this a bug?

tl;dr 
Can't find "create new custom dimension" button. Am I blind?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more related to configuration. You should post this to Webmasters instead.

Comment: I've reported it as a bug but wanted to see if anyone else has experienced it here and have a fix for it / can confirm it's a UI bug of some sorts. But, fair enough, I'll post this somewhere else then.